Allowing specific apps only during specific focus?
What I want
I have the Work focus scheduled during my work hours. I have several work-related apps that I would like to allow notifications from only whenever I happen to have the Work focus on. Otherwise, I don't want to hear from them.
What I tried

Disabling the notifications for these apps under Settings → Notifications and then specifically whitelisting them in the Work focus settings. This didn't work because, I guess, Notifications settings have priority and a focus can't overwrite them.

Considered re-enabling notifications for these work-related apps and then scheduling the Personal focus for hours outside work, where I would disable them. But that sounds too much because I don't really need a focus for my personal time (except for this issue). I am not sure what other restrictions it would impose and it would show up to other people in iMessage as if I do not want to be disturbed.


So is there a way to allow specific apps only during a specific focus and mute them otherwise?
